# Chrome Extension: Make window attach to side of browser and always on top?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to create a popup window that appears on the side  of browser and attaches itself without disappearing under the browser window when it's maximized. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried to create a new window with type "panel"?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows, has alwaysonTop option but when the chrome window is maximize it hides under it.

Comment: Then I'm afraid that it's not possible.